# Is solipsism truly unprovable?

Tags: metaphysics, proof, solipsism

I know I’ve asked a lot of these but this one I’m hoping to be definitive.

I have heard pretty much everyone say that it’s unprovable, that you can’t know for sure if it’s true or not because of the nature of the question. And that did bug me for a bit but I can accept that, some stuff in life is just like that.

But then I came across a post on Quora that at the time I strongly felt proved solipsism to be true. Though I don’t remember the post or question or what the answer said I just have a strong feeling that it proved it.

But I began thinking, since I can’t remember the content at all, how could anyone do that? I mean isn’t solipsism at best just uncertainty about the external world and other minds and at worst denial of anything but you. You can’t design an experiment to prove it because that would be trusting something other than your existence. When you doubt everything but yourself you can’t really prove your point to anyone else, right?

And I know people will laugh but I googled it and nothing came up about it being proven. Not a one. Just stuff saying you either can’t, or how it is consistent as a framework, but nothing proving it true. Which seems to lend credence to it being unprovable. I mean if in all the thousands of years of philosophy no one has done it then that kinda answer that question right? From everything I’m able to gather there isn’t a way to know if it’s true or not, it’s impossible.

Im just asking if this is truly the case. Yes I’m also aware of the irony of someone posting on the internet to someone’s question about if solipsism is true or not.

I was also under the impression that as a metaphysical position you can’t really test it or prove it, or is that wrong too about metaphysical positions.

Comment: Here is another question for you: does it really matter? For all practical purposes, whether you are the only mind in the world conjuring up a Matrix like fantasy, or whether there are other minds, it's all the same for practical purposes.

Comment: And here is another thought: would there be an informal argument against solipsism from probabilities? if your mind is alone and really conjured up all that you see, hear, feel, ... there are many coincidences. Your mind is truly extremely powerful if it can reliably produce that very elaborate fantasy, which contains "others" that seem to come up to your consciousness "at random". Does that sound likely to you?

Comment: "I have heard pretty much everyone say that it’s unprovable... From everything I’m able to gather there isn’t a way to know if it’s true or not, it’s impossible." How would someone saying the same thing one more time here make it any more definitive?

Comment: See [this post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/98408/does-this-paper-prove-solipsism-is-true)

Comment: If solipsism is true why come here ask other minds what they think about it?

Comment: I have long wondered why there are not more solipsists.

Comment: @Frank It would make a difference because it would affect my interactions with everything around me. If I’m all there is there wouldn’t be a reason to do anything. There would be nothing to learn, no one to help, it would be a pointless existence. Living a life without friends or partners and having to pretend all the time other people are real. People say it’s the same but it’s not the same for all practical purposes, it’s wildly different.

Comment: @DarkNeos That's assuming you can *know* your situation.

Comment: Consider looking in to Nonduality.

Comment: @ScottRowe Nonduality doesn’t change the problem of solipsism, I’ve checked.

Comment: @Frank what do you mean by that? Are you saying that our situation is at most just a best guess of things?

Comment: @DarkNeos I meant that if the possible illusion is perfect, whether we know or not doesn't matter?

Comment: Nonduality doesn't change the problem of solipsism, it just makes you uninterested in getting caught up in conceptual, discursive thought.

Comment: @Frank It does matter though. If something is an illusion then it can’t love me back or feel pain, it can’t be helped either. It matters a lot whether something is real or not.

Comment: @ScottRowe Id have to disagree as nonduality isn’t a practical philosophy to live by for one, and second you’re still caught up in it. If anything it might even reinforce solipsism by suggesting you are everything. That’s why I said it doesn’t work.

Comment: @DarkNeos But whatever is out there does "love you back pain" or "feel pain". The illusion is so perfect, it gives all the signals that it does feel those things. There is not really any reason to ask the question: "is this real"?

Comment: No, it insists that you are nothing. That's what makes it practical. It is the end of being caught up in things. You can play along, or pretend, but it all pretty clearly is just a massive collective delusion. As Bart Marshall said, "*I came unfooled.*" Not to be taken for a fool so easily again.

Comment: Someone Upvoted your question and the answers. Ok, it was me. Your own rules say that you can't upvote your posts, therefore Solipsism is untrue. QED

Comment: @Frank But it doesn’t. You mention illusion meaning that you know it isn’t one. The illusion isn’t perfect and you know all the signals are false. That’s what I meant on the alleged Quora answer. There is every reason to ask if it’s real. Like I keep telling you there is a world of difference between the illusion and real thing.

Comment: @ScottRowe But it isn’t though, that’s just you deluding yourself. Also nonduality isn’t that you are nothing, that’s a common mistake. But it’s just jumping into a deception not being unfooled. And again it still falls prey to solipsism.

Comment: I have long wondered why there are not more solipsists.

Comment: @BobaFit Because the position cuts against our disposition to see minds everywhere, even where they don't exist like in trees or in magical places atop mountains or in the sky. ChatGPT is just the latest incarnation of false trigger. Our brains are finely tuned to identify and collaborate with others genetically.

Comment: @JD I couldn't have said it better myself.

Comment: @JD but doesn’t that argument favor solipsism

Comment: @DarkNeos It explains solipsism, but it does not favor it. The difference lies in the fact that solipsism is an intuition that occurs at the beginning of the philosophical impulse to reason. You wanna know what proof is in it's simplest form? Nothing more than persuasion, and human thinkers evolve from not seeing others' mind, to developing a theory of mind, to questioning the theory of mind, to overcoming the radical skepticism that others don't exist. Once you have children, have a spouse, take care of pets, and watch the light extinguish in the elderly, it's tough to reject them with words.

Comment: @JD what if someone did manage to prove solipsism or said they did?

Comment: The silence after that makes me tend to think that someone did prove it, like a sort of entity A bomb.

Answer (score 5):

Solipsism is unprovable because of the nature of our interactions with the world.

In simple terms, the idea would be this:
We can never access the world "as it is". Even conceptually, that is a meaningless idea because our entire experience of the world is grounded in our systems of perception. These systems interpret and all we see is our own subjective interpretation. We cannot prove or disprove things outside of this interpretation because we have no access to things beyond this interpretation.

Or, in a more formal sense:

1. We only have access to our own minds
2. We don't have access to the existence of things outside of our own minds
3. If we want to prove or disprove solipsism, then we'd have to prove or disprove the existence of things outside of our own minds.
4. If we want to prove or disprove x, then we need access to it.
5. Therefore, we cannot prove or disprove things outside of our mind
6. Therefore, we cannot prove or disprove solipsism.

**The Caveat**

Now, that said, a lot of the time philosophy isn't about proving or disproving things. Rather, it's about the intuitive force and appeal of certain positions, the costs that come with them, and the evidence around them. Maybe solipsism can't be proven, but given our experiences is solipsism *likely?* Does it fit naturally within our metaphysical positions? What does it generate to?

Existentialist philosophers, for example, would reject lots of versions of solipsism because they claim that our existence is fundamentally an experience of the world. Heidegger would say that the existence of other people and the world is undeniably a structural part of being human, and therefore ridiculous to doubt. Sartre would say that the Other is an important part of what gives us identity.

Some contemporary philosophers claim that broad scepticism with solipsistic flavours are only academic, no one can actually genuinely believe in it as a position and so it may not be worth discussing. Others discuss different flavours of it when talking about other minds.

[The Problem of Other Minds](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/other-minds/#PercKnowOtheMindPhenTrad) and general [Sceptical Arguments](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/skepticism/#KnowJustSkep) might be a good place to start thinking about questions like these.

(For a similar debate about an unprovable question, look at [the Problem of Evil](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/evil/). The debate here also quickly moves on from, "can we prove x?" to "what are the implications of x? Is x likely? etc".)

Comment: That seemed to be my first response when I thought they proved it. 

Not only can you not read minds but to prove solipsism true would require omniscience. We cannot get outside of our own heads so anyone claiming to have proven solipsism true would be wrong. Even if we could get out of our own head that would likely still lead to the same issues about whether we can tell it’s real or not.

Comment: Yep. The problem is fundamentally about our access to the world. 

Usually proofs for solipsism or proofs against it are more arguments grounded in assumptions. For example, Descartes arguments in Meditations are largely grounded in assumptions about the nature of God.

Comment: So even if someone “proved it true” it would still be resting on assumptions that they cannot test right? I mean I’m comfortable with being unsure as I can just dismiss it after that point. It goes back to what I was saying, you’d need omniscience to prove it true or false because only then could you have utter certainty of your perception.

Comment: Well, either assumptions they cannot test or assumptions that are potentially unsound (i.e. just wrong). You're right, you need omniscience to prove it.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot disprove that there is a planet in Andromeda populated by clones of Marilyn Monroe- does that mean I should believe it? There are countless unprovable ideas, but the fact that an idea cannot be disproved does not necessarily make it credible. Extreme forms of solipsism are clearly nonsense, notwithstanding the fact that it might be impossible to disprove them. One can, of course, point out no end of ludicrous implications of extreme solipsism. For example, it is clearly inconsistent, in that the solipsist's mind imposes all kinds of limitations on the ability of the solipsist, and yet it allows the solipsist to imagine people speaking Chinese, calculating pi to n-trillion decimal places, inventing General `Relativity and performing no end of other activities which the solipsist himself is entirely incapable of performing. But no amount of common sense argument is sufficient to satisfy the committed solipsist, who, in that regard at least, is certainly not alone in the world of philosophy.

Comment: Yes, the idea that one's mental creations could be smarter than oneself seems like a deal breaker. But sometimes I do have experiences of a character in a dream solving a problem that I couldn't, or a personality character (like in a book I am thinking about and writing) solving problems in waking life. Minds are pretty amazing.

Comment: @ScottRowe I know what you mean. And after all, it would be hard for me to imagine  someone smarter than myself!

Comment: But what if this alleged Quora post did manage to prove it true.

Comment: @DarkNeos if the post did prove it true, then you do not exist and I would be led to the contradictory conclusion that neither did the person who penned the post, therefore they could not have proved the point that led me to assume their non-existence.

Comment: @MarcoOcram So even if they allegedly did it wouldn’t be something that could be trusted or verified right?

Comment: @MarcoOcram So by that logic no one would be able to prove it true then right?

Answer (score 1):

I would differentiate between **epistemological solipsism** (*I am certain only for my existence*, a-la Descartes) from **metaphysical solipsism** (*I am the only thing that exists*).

One does not necessarily lead to the other. Even Descartes (Meditations) started from epistemological solipsism yet arrived at realism.

One can doubt the premise of epistemological solipsism as well (eg we are equally certain of other things besides ourselves. In the same sense I know for certain what is "me", I can know for certain what is "not-me" and I perceive things which I know they are "not-me", since I know what is "me").

In any case, metaphysical solipsism is easier to counteract. Metaphysical solipsism is the thesis that only "I" exist (*sole ipso*) and everything is either my creation, or is experienced because I am its ultimate purpose (being the only thing existing). It is hard and highly problematic and incoherent to phrase metaphysical solipsism differently.

This thesis necessarily makes the subject omnipotent, either directly (as creator) or indirectly (being the ultimate purpose of everything).

We are demonstrably not omnipotent, thus metaphysical solipsism must be false.

Once one doubts metaphysical solipsism, epistemological solipsism can follow, since we now necessarily know there are other things (besides ourselves) that exist as well

Hope these help.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I prefer to view things in terms of weighing reasons rather than in terms of proof. Strictly speaking, nothing can be *proved* to be true or false except logical and mathematical theorems. The point, then, is rather if solipsism can be justified or not, whether there are good reasons to be a solipsist, and less good reasons not to be one. And, I don't know for you, but as far as I am concerned the evidence *against* solipsism seems overwhelming.

If there was nobody around, I would have good reasons to be a solipsist, but there are many people on earth. If I could easily control the phenomena I experience too, or if there were no contingencies, but many things that happen to me were unpredictable and outside of my control. If other people were very distinct from me, if they were not expressing emotions, maybe I could think that they are sophisticated automats or artefacts of my consciousness, but other people are more or less like me. Or if I could witness evidence that people are merely pretending to be conscious and switched behaviour when they think I'm not here, for example, or if there were inconsistencies in what I take to be reality, I would have reasons to doubt, but I haven't witnessed anything like this so far.

Comment: +1 "Personally I prefer to view things in terms of weighing reasons rather than in terms of proof. Strictly speaking, nothing can be proved to be true or false except logical and mathematical theorems." And even then, a constructivist rejects some proofs a non-constructivist accepts begging the question of whose theory of proof, if any, is best?

Answer (score -1):

No, some arguments to unprove Solipsisim are:

**1. Wittgenstein's “Private Language”** There is no such thing as a “private language.” We learned the language we use to think with. We did not invent our “native” language, or our “1st language.”

Imagine trying to invent a whole private language, even putting aside not having anyone to communicate with through it. Who would understand it?

The best explanation of the fact of language is that through an historical process other minds created and transmitted language to us.

So there are other minds.

Credit: Lou Reich

**2. Problem of Other Hemispheres / Split Brain**

The sceptical Problem Of Other Minds will be solved by biotechnology. Compare people born without a corpus callosum to connect their cerebral hemispheres, or “split brain” patients who’ve had their corpus callosum surgically severed to treat epilepsy. If one hemisphere entertains doubts whether the other hemisphere is really conscious (aka the Problem Of Other Hemispheres), then currently the sceptical hemisphere can’t prove the sentience of its twin. However, advanced biotech promises corpora callosa grown to order, laying sceptical doubts to rest. More radically, artificially-grown corpora callosa and reversible thalamic bridges will let neurotypical humans partially “mind-meld” like the conjoined Hogan sisters today. So yes, solipsism can, in principle, be scientifically disproved.

Credit:David Pearce

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-brain

**3.Sartre's Emotion Argument**

Sartre held that the feeling of shame proved solipsism, and idealism to be false. If we are caught peeping at someone undressing in the toilet then we feel ashamed. If solpsism or idealism were true, this feeling would be false. But since we all have this feeling at one time or another Sartre held that there must exist other conscious bodies. The trouble with this is it reduces proof to emotion. It then follows that our opinion of what is real reduces to how we feel about it.

https://that-which.com/sartre-solipsism-the-problem-of-other-minds-and-the-look/

Heidegger and Sartre on the Problem of Other ... https://philarchive.org/archive/CAOHAS

Credit: Andrew j. Turner

**4.Quantum Mechanics**

The key point is that a realist explanation of quantum experiments requires the existence of something directly represented by the quantum state or something that can simulate the quantum state,while the mental state is a classical state in the sense that it is always definite and its content contains only information about macroscopics ystems such as the setting of apreparation apparatus, which is not enough for representing or simulating the quantum state. A positive result of this analysis is that one finds the existence of anexternal world besidesone’s mind.

Quantum mechanics refutes solipsism:A proof of the existence of an external world https://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/22361/